# datatables called twice randomly results in empty tables

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using `Datatable` to display a table with 5 tabs. After debugging for a while I noticed that each call to the database is done twice. The first call returns an empty JSON and the second one the proper data. This causes the table not to be populated when the second group of calls ends before the first one is finished.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
} );
  var table = $('table.table').DataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,     
      "ajax": {
          "dataSrc": "Data",
          "url": "my_controller/getDataTable",
          "data": { string: $("input.form-control").val() },// gets the value from the hidden search field and check the db with this string (i.e "job2")
          "type": "POST"
      },
      "columns": [
          { "data": "name" },
          { "data": "eff" },
          { "data": "sal" },
          { "data": "id",       // The data to use in the link
               "render": function(data,type,row,meta) {
                 var a = "<a href='some_url'><button>hire</button>";
                 return a;
               }
           }
        ]
        });
        // Apply a search to the other tables to filter the list automatically
        $('#myTable1').DataTable().search( 'job1' ).draw();
        $('#myTable2').DataTable().search( 'job2' ).draw();
        $('#myTable3').DataTable().search( 'job3' ).draw();
        $('#myTable4').DataTable().search( 'job4' ).draw();
        $('#myTable5').DataTable().search( 'job5' ).draw();
```

Here is a snapshot of Firebug:
[image]

I don't understand which part of my code is causing the problem.

If I remove the `.draw` at the end, only the empty responses are there...

Comment: You instantiating every table with your first use of `.DataTable()`, and your doing it again when you use `.DataTable().search( 'job1' ).draw();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating every table with your first use of `.DataTable()`, and your doing it again when you use `.DataTable().search( 'job1' ).draw();`

You can use `column().search()` to filter single columns in your tables.
[Source](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

```
$('#myTable1').columns(ColumnIndex).search('job1').draw();
```

**Update**

```
var table1 = initializeTable($("#myTable1"));
var table2 = initializeTable($("#myTable2"));

function initializeTable(tbl){
    return tbl.DataTable({
        ...setup table...
    });
}

table1.columns(ColumnIndex).search('job1').draw();
table2.columns(ColumnIndex).search('job2').draw();
```

Comment: I tried `$('#myTable1').column(1).search('job1').draw();` that but I get `$(...).column is not a function`. Same if I used `columns` instead.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to set each table as a variable. I'll provide an example.

Comment: Your code would return all the jobs in each table (looks like it is not filtered). I needed to initialize the tables with `var table1 = initializeTable($("#myTable1"),'job1');` and pass a new variable `staff_type` in `"data": { string: staff_type }` and  `function initializeTable(tbl, staff_type){`. The tables are still called twice but each of them returns a data. It works fine even if there is probably room for improvement. Thanks!